# How can I tell if it's day or night when I can't see the sun?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

In Dragon Quest XI, after

> the World Tree falls down from the sky, the sun no longer shines. It's always dark, however the following events prove there is still a day/night cycle:

- I can still camp/rest until Dawn
- There is still a "change to day/night" clip

> The monsters are also the same in both cases, so can't be used as indication.

How can I tell if it's day or night?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be trivial. In the Map page, there is a "compass" showing the time of day:

[image]

(<sub><sup>[image source](https://www.gamerguides.com/dragon-quest-xi-echoes-of-an-elusive-age/extras/crossbow-kid/laguna-di-gondolia)</sup></sub>)

I noticed this only after sun got back, but pretty sure it was always there, and I just missed it.